# Need podcast endpoints from web API

Tags: javascript, api, spotify, webapi

I'm trying to pull data from the Spotify API such as "popular podcasts" or "podcasts by genre". But as you can see from the documentation, to get podcast info you must have the podcast (or "show") id, which you can only get from doing a search with "show" as a parameter. Is there anything I'm missing?

[Spotify Docs - Podcast Endpoints](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/shows/)

Comment: Looking at the API documentation, these endpoints don't exist on the API.

Comment: Please add a link to the API docs in qusetion, so people can help you better. :)